# Linq query with where against a nullable field

Tags: c#, linq

I'm converting some old sql select statements to linq, and I've hit a stupid moment. The database is fixed so bad designs are permanent.

The sql statement is this;

`WHERE xTD.Transaction_Type IN (9,10,11,12,19)`

so I coded

`List<int> transTypes = new List<int>() {9,10,11,12,19};`

with a where clause of

`where transTypes.Contains(xTD.Transaction_Type)`

the problem is that xTd.Transaction_Type is a nullable field. What's the syntax to make this work?

Sorry but it's Friday and I can't even get google to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where xTD.Transaction_Type.HasValue && transTypes.Contains(xTD.Transaction_Type.Value)
```

Comment: Mahdipc, sorry, Tim got here first but your answer works also. Thank you guys! The first beer is on my tonight if you get to Long Island!

Comment: @BernieHunt: If his answer works too, he's the one who should get the first beer. But i think its not working because he doesn't check if the nullable has a value. So it throws an exception if the value is null.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean,

```
 where transTypes.Contains(xTD.Transaction_Type.value)
```